# For an Inline Vf Page how can I get the id of the current object?

Tags: apex, visualforce, inline-visualforce

For an Inline Vf Page how can I get the id of the current object. I want to have the current object id . how can i retieve it use for an inline vf page.

I am embedding it in an Object A while the VF page points to the junction Object of A and B i.e., C. On the Controller, I need the object id Of A so that I may be able to save record of relating A and B.

Answer (score 4):

If you have a controller, you could use `ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Id')`.

If you have only Visualforce, you can use `{!$CurrentPage.parameters.Id}`

Or you can use JavaScript to read the parameters form the `window.location.search` property. Therefore the following function was helpful for me:

```
function getUriParams(paramName) {
    var params = decodeURIComponent(window.location.search.slice(1))
          .split('&')
          .reduce(function _reduce (/*Object*/ a, /*String*/ b) {
                b = b.split('=');
                a[b[0]] = b[1];
                return a;
          }, {})
    ;
    if(paramName) return params[paramName]; else return params;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're using the Standard Controller, you can get the ID directly from the record:

```
<apex:page standardController="Account">
    The current Account Id is: {!Account.Id}. That is all.
</apex:page>
```

Comment: I am embedding it in an Object A while the VF page points to the junction Object A and B i.e., C. On the Controller, I need the object id Of A so that I may be able to save record of relating A and B.

Comment: @user2703132 That said, the other answer may be more appropriate in this scenario. Sometimes, knowing the correct tool or programming method to use is half the fun of programming in Visualforce.